# How to disable firefox from opening while running test suite in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am writing test scripts in Selenium IDE for my application but everytime when I run the test suite it opens up browser and performs all the actions and logs failures, if any. My requirement is to invoke the test script from command prompt using .bat file and generate a test report. I am able to do the same but the problem is firefox opens up and executes the test case one by one. Can anyone please suggest me how to disable Firefox window from opening up? Or is it just not possible to do so? Or do I need to switch to Selenium Webdriver in order to achieve my requirement? My application contains Ajax upto a lot of extent.

I have read many commands used in Selenium IDE but I could not find any command which can serve this purpose. Please suggest!

Answer (score 2):

If you know any programming language supported by [`selenium-webdriver`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) (`Ruby`, `Java`, `Python`, `C#`) then you should try [`PhantomJS WebDriver`](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html) which allow to run scripts without opening visual browser session

Answer (score 1):

Selenium-IDE are mean to invoke browser, that's how the script react to all the exact browser behavior.

Only selenium Webdriver allow you to run your browser under "Headless" mode, which in fact, put Firefox under X-virtual frame buffer in background, as above @Andersson suggested.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to convert your Selenium-IDE script to your desire programming language at the moment.

If your concern is about "cluttered screen" in OS such as ubuntu, then your solution will be export the whole Selenium-IDE and firefox under another virtual X-display.